# Grails - Access request object in domain class

Tags: grails, dns, request

Is there a possibility to access the properties of the `request` object within a method of a domain class?

Thus, I would like to access `request.getRemoteAddr()` inside `beforeInsert()` and `beforeUpdate()` of my domain base class in order to save the IP-Address automatically and would not have to code it within every controller.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should never do like that, my recommendation is that you create a Service based on your Domain Class, and every times you need to modify it, call these functions save(), update() from your controllers or other services. your Domain Class should never do any business logic!

Comment: Thank you @hakuna1811 - I will bear that in mind. Is it then possible to access a `request` object from within the service class or should I set the value within the controller and then just use the service class to save the domain object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't access the `request` or `session` in your domain class directly, as you can never know, in which context the domain object gets saved/updated. This is by design.

If the situation is really desperate, you can use a workaround:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder 

def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
```